# Performance: Select count(*) where... VS select column_name where

Tags: performance, select, odbc, query-performance

I'll keep the scenario simple:

- There is an app, and there is a database.
- In the database, there is a table with a **large** amount of records
- I feed the app these records regularly

Now, one reload can imply some of these changes:
  i. New records in set
  ii. Updated records in set
  iii. Deleted records in set

Finally, for records that remain the same I can make use of a diferent process that works as much as 100 times faster than reading the table through ODBC.

Knowing this, I am trying to reduce the reloading time by using the ODBC as little as possible and midway through my algorithm I encounter a question that I have not been able to solve.

**How much faster is a `select count(*) where [condition]` opposed to `select columnName where [condition]`

Why? Because just by reloading the new and updated records, I can calculate whether there have been deletions or not by counting records depending on [condition]. Then, if there have been deletions, I'll have to read from the database those that remain. Nornally, the amount of new and updated records will be a small portion of the whole set.
If a *count* is considerably faster than a normal select, I might want to use it as a fast check, since deleting records is not a common activity.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? But in general the `count(*)` will be faster as it will only return a **single** row whereas the other query will return _many_ rows

Comment: I honestly do not know just yet. All I know is that it will be located in a datalake and that I will mosy likely be asked to use Impala. My guess is that it will be an Oracle (MariaDB).

Comment: Anyway, is that the only difference? The amount of rows returned (and its content ofc)? Is there no performance difference apart from the "building" of more rows?

Comment: I consider that a huge difference... (Also MariaDB and Oracle are **very** different database systems)

Comment: Is that so? Newby me thought it didn't really make that big a difference in query time. Thank you very much! (Also, I do not know what crossed my mind to link Oracle and MariaDB, sry about that)

Comment: How big do you think the difference between sending a single number e.g. 3645535 over the wire and sending 3645535 rows with 500 byte of data over the wire is? The first one is something about 100 bytes (with protocol overhead), the second one sends about 1.5 **GB** over the wire

Comment: Absolutely right. I was just trying to figure query time, not the time between making the query and getting the response (which is what I was actually trying to reduce in the first place). Thanks! You can post the answer and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on a database you use while executing the query and gathered statistics.

1. **Oracle DB.**  If stats have already been gathered , the first query would return the amount of rows in 0.00001 sec. If have not been, then it will be faster in five more times than while executing the second query as it is retrieving large amount of rows instead of just one.
2. For **MS SQL** will be almost the same thing.
3. For **MySQL** or **MariaDB** it depends on the engine. But I assume these databases always try caching the value of amount of rows as the optimizer will do queries faster.

In addition, columns in `WHERE` clause and in `COUNT()` do matter as well. They could be indexes or not and etc. There are lot of criteria considering perfomance between the queries but in the most cases the first one is recommended for using to get amount of rows. I could tell you more precisely if I had certain example.

Comment: Nice and detailed explanation :D just to top it all, there would not happen to be a kind of formula to compare the results depending on the parameters that you point out, right? Or I just have to try the different options to know? (I'm not being lazy, I just like to work on paper)

Comment: I think it will be a lot of parameters in a function depending on a situation... Too heavy to write